# Unable to click on Image icon which is displayed using WatiN

Tags: visual-studio-2010, watin

I am using WatiN for automation.

I have a screen were two options are displayed "Search" and "Filter", with only one option enabled at once.

By default, search is enabled. I am able to click on "Filter" and perform filtering operations, but when i try to click on the search option (An Image) am getting a message as "Element is disabled".

Can anyone please suggest how can we click on a disabled image using WatiN?
This was working fine sometime ago, but it started failing at the point where i am switching back to Search.

Thanks & Regards,
Kumar

Answer (score 1):

Can you post some of the code that you are using for these actions.

My guess is that you are identifying the search and filter buttons initially and at that time the search button is disabled. And due to some reason, the change in the DOM state is not reflected in the object. If my supposition is correct, either one of these actions might help

OPTION 1

```
Image search = // Identify the image button for search;
Image filter = // Identify the image button for filter;

/// Perform filtering ops

search.Refresh();
search.Click();
```

If this does not help,

OPTION 2

```
/// Perform filtering ops
search = /// Identify the image button from the DOM now;
search.Click();
```

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct. I identify the objects first than perform filter later switch back to search. I tried the first approach it did not work and the second one, when you say "dentify the image button from the DOM now;" is it just identifying the object again or is this anything different? Because even this did not worked.

Comment: yes, i meant that you should identify the object again. Too bad, that too didnt work. please post if you had any breakthrough in this.